# React MSAL multi instance with Azure AD and Azure ADB2C

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have one web applicaiton in React, that uses Azure AD for login(Employee only). I want to provide access to External users as well(Clients) and for the same I want to use Azure ADB2C.

For testing purpose I provide B2C specific confiuration and that worked well(with some additional configuration).
Is there any way to provide mixed mode login support(AD and ADB2C) in same applicaiton with single MsalProvider?

```
"config": {
      "auth": {
        "authority": "@@@@@@@@",
        "clientId": "@@@@@@@@",
        "redirectUri": "http://localhost:9000",
        "postLogoutRedirectUri": "http://localhost:9000",
        "navigateToLoginRequestUrl": false
      },
      "cache": {
        "cacheLocation": "localStorage",
        "storeAuthStateInCookie": true
      }
    }
```

```
const pca = new PublicClientApplication(authConfig);

ReactDOM.render(
  <MsalProvider instance={pca}>
    <App />
  </MsalProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Referene code https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add [Azure AD federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) to B2C.

Comment: Thanks rbrayb, this worked well